# Running two different screens in same time in libgdx

Tags: java, kotlin, libgdx, game-physics, box2d

I want to render 2 different screens in same times. When I touch the pause button, new and small sized screen should be able to seem on first screen without disposing FirstScreen. How can i do this.

[image: The pic of my idea]

Answer (score 0):

You can chain render methods. In the first screen render method, add

```
...
if (pauseButtonPressed) {
    smallScreen.render();
}
...
```

As long as you ***don't*** call

```
gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
```

the second screen will be drawn on top of the first. All screens are full sized and there is no viewport to allow rendering to a screen section, so you must stay within your desired bounds of the small screen as part of the render overlay code.

Also, `dispose()` allows you to release resources (memory) used when the screen is no longer needed, its not how you remove the screen.